# What is the area of the inscnibed square?

Tags: geometry

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xwoV.jpg

Triangles $ABC$ and $DEF$ are right triangles with $AB = CB = DE = EF$. If the area of the inscribed square $X$ is $441$, what is the area of the inscnibed square region labeled $Y$?

Comment: Notice that triangle ABC can fit exactly two square X's inside of it, using the fact that its two smaller sides are of equal length. Now that you know that both triangles have an area of 2 square X's, can you find Y?

Answer (score 2):

Both triangles are equivalent isoceles right angled triangles. Notice that interior angles are $45-90-45$ degrees. Let $AB=CB=DE=EF=a$.

In the first figure (on the left), the side of the square is $\frac{a}{2}$. Since $X=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2$, we have $a^2=1764$.

In the second figure, the side of the square is one-third of the hyphotenuse, so it is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}a$.  Hence, $Y=\frac{2}{9}a^2=392$.

We have $Y=\frac{8}{9}X$. So, $Y$ is the smaller square.